# Can't list com ports of my laptop (java, cmd)

Tags: java, powershell, intellij-idea, cmd, serial-port

With the following java code I was going to list the com ports:

```
import gnu.io.*;

public class DataInputStream {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new DataInputStream().listPorts();
    }

    public static void listPorts()
    {
        System.out.println("in listPorts");

        java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() )
        {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName()  +  " - " +  getPortName(portIdentifier.getPortType()) );
        }
    }

    public static String getPortName ( int portType )
    {
        System.out.println("in getPortName");

        switch ( portType )
        {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_I2C:
                return "I2C";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                return "Parallel";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RAW:
                return "Raw";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RS485:
                return "RS485";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                return "Serial";
            default:
                return "unknown Type";
        }
    }
}
```

It executes in intelliJ without any exceptions, but there are no com ports listed. It also seems like the getPortName method is not reached, since the println is not printed.

I've also tried listing the com ports with the cmd command:

```
C:\>wmic path Win32_SerialPort
```

and with the powershell command:

```
PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort
```

In cmd it says "No instance(s) available." But what does that mean?
The powershell command does nothing. There are no error messages but no outputs either.

However, I can plug in devices in the com ports and Windows recognizes them, so they are obviously working. Do I need some special rights to access the com ports? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure about Java. Have you tried opening the PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari: How would I do that?

Comment: Search powershell from start menu, right click and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari: Ok, I've done that but still nothing. It just executes without printing anything.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure your laptop is actually equipped with a serial port (sorry to ask that, but if 3 tools result in 'none', I feel like I have to)...

Comment: @aschipfl: Well, I do have one serial port. But even if I didn't, the switch statement in the java code provides a default case for unrecognized ports. It's just strange it doesn't list anything at all...